# stuck with trying to filter dates in a json object using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and I need advice on the best way to filter dates in a JSON object that is populated from a fetch call to an API.

I have a Date range picker component that sets the state with the chosen dates. at page load the the data is populated into an HTML table, when the user selects the chosen dates from the date range picker and clicks the filter button I need the html table to be updated with results that fall between the chosen date ranges.

my constructor has the starting state:

```
this.state = {
  bookings: {},
  selectionRange : {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
    key: "selection"
  }
}
```

My Date Button to filter the dates, my attempt to convert the date from a string to a valid date.

```
onbuttonsubmit()  {
  var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
  console.log("Testing:", new Date(this.state.bookings.FromDate).toLocaleDateString([],options));
}
     
<button onButtonSubmit={this.onbuttonsubmit}>Filter Dates</button>
```

I have attached an image showing the bookings{} json:

[image]

Comment: so you need `FromDate` to be between the date range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `FromDate` at your bookings object is a string and filters are of type `Date`, you could do the following, provided that you want to do a search based on `FromDate`:

```
 onbuttonsubmit = () =>  {
    this.setState( { bookings : this.state.bookings.filter( book => new Date(book.FromDate).getTime() >= this.state.startDate.getTime() && new Date(book.FromDate).getTime() <= this.state.endDate.getTime())});
}
```

Comment: thank you,  I have done what you suggested but I am getting typeError:  cannot read property setState of undefined

Comment: ok so you havent binded the method. see my updated answer then.

Comment: Apostolos, since my book.fromDate is a json string "2019-06-14T00:00:00" the .getTime() is not valid, could I create a function within a function to resolve this?  ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined

Comment: it is `new Date(book.FromDate).getTime()`. this is valid

Comment: try at your console this `new Date('2019-04-26T00:00:00').getTime()` to see that it is working

Comment: confirmed that this works :) just unsure as to why it will not work from your code snippet Apostolos

Comment: don't know since i dont have full access to your code. based on what you have provided, this is one solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219132/discussion-between-apostolos-and-dbjoe).